# Default profile picture for new user using createUserWithEmailAndPassword in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a default profile picture for every user to chooses the signIn method as signinwithEmail.

Here is my code :

```
Future<FirebaseUser> signUpWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    AuthResult authResult = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);

    String url = 'assets/images/default_icon.png';

    if (authResult != null) {
      UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
      updateInfo.displayName = email;
      updateInfo.photoUrl = url;

      FirebaseUser firebaseUser = authResult.user;

      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        await firebaseUser.updateProfile(updateInfo);

        await firebaseUser.reload();

        FirebaseUser currentuser = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();


        return currentuser;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I have added the image to my assets folder still I am getting an error as  :
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///assets/images/default_image.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2313:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2208:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:90:59)
#3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:51:14)
#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
#5      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:360:22)
#6      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:80)
#7      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:108:19)

Image provider: NetworkImage("assets/images/default_image.png", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("assets/images/default_image.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: You cant use an Asset Image inside Network Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL that you are saving in Firebase is the path to your local image asset, which cannot be passed to a `NetworkImage` widget.

In other words, the local image is not a valid URL or hosted on the internet, so you cannot use it in the `NetworkImage` widget.

Now, to solve your issue, you can do two things:

1. Check whether the user has chosen the `signInWithEmail` method & use `Image.asset` instead of `NetworkImage`.
2. Upload your image to your server / Firebase & provide the uploaded image's URL.

Comment: I tried to add network image but still facing the same issue .

Comment: My issue is resolved after re-building the application it takes a network image.

Comment: Okay, that's great.